# Need explanation : Generic friendliness to avoid casting, this is not anymore needed in Java 8

Tags: java, generics, java-8, mockito

```
* @deprecated With Java 8 this method will be removed in Mockito 3.0. This method is only used for generic
 * friendliness to avoid casting, this is not anymore needed in Java 8.
 */
public static <T> List<T> anyListOf(Class<T> clazz) {
    return anyList();
}
```

I was looking into the Mockito source code and came across this deprecated method, can anyone explain how this is being handled in Java 8. An example would be appreciated on how I can call a generic method without using this method as an argument for it.

```
@Test
public void getDataTest() {
    when(dataSetDao.getDataSetList()).thenReturn(getMockDataSetList());
    when(serviceUtil.getDataFromEndpoint(anyInt(), anyList(), anyString(), any(TypeToken.class), anyString())).thenReturn(getMockDataList());
    List<Data> dataList = noaaDataService.getData();
    verify(serviceUtil, times(11)).getDataFromEndpoint(anyInt(), anyList(), anyString(), any(TypeToken.class), anyString());
    assertEquals(11, dataList.size());

}

private <T> List<T> getMockDataList() {
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
        dataList.add(new Data());
    }
    return (List<T>) dataList;
}
```

Cannot resolve method 'thenReturn(java.util.List). This is the error I receive when I call the method in the way mentioned above.

Can someone explain why I am getting this error if type inference has been improved in Java 8.

Method being called :

```
/**
 * Generic method to fetch data from rest endpoint.
 *
 * @param offset       Default should be 0, recursive call in place would increase it till we have fetched all the records.
 * @param dataList     List to be returned and passed on to the recursive call.
 * @param postFixUrl   End point to be used.
 * @param responseType Used to convert the response into json, need this so that we will know the generic type at compile time.
 * @param <T>          Entity for which we are fetching the data.
 * @param arguments    Arguments to be passed to the uri.
 * @return A list of T derived from the response.
 */
public <T> List<T> getDataFromEndpoint(
    int offset, List<T> dataList, String postFixUrl,
    TypeToken<ArrayList<T>> responseType, String arguments)
```

Temporary fix to get around the problem, is there a better way to do this.

```
@Test
public void getDataTest() {
    when(dataSetDao.getDataSetList()).thenReturn(getMockDataSetList());
    when(serviceUtil.getDataFromEndpoint(anyInt(), anyList(), anyString(), any(TypeToken.class), anyString())).thenReturn(getMockDataList(Data.class));
    List<Data> dataList = noaaDataService.getData();
    verify(serviceUtil, times(11)).getDataFromEndpoint(anyInt(), anyList(), anyString(), any(TypeToken.class), anyString());
    assertEquals(11, dataList.size());

}

private <T> List<T> getMockDataList(T type) {
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
        dataList.add(new Data());
    }
    return (List<T>) dataList;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Type inference has been improved in Java 8.

Comment: I believe you replace `anyListOf()` calls with `anyList()` calls.

Comment: I tried that earlier but it is giving me an error with that, I have updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: In 8, method arguments are included in order to find out the target type, looks lke this is what is going on here

Comment: I updated the method getMockDataList() to take a generic argument in order to get around the error, is there a better way to resolve this issue. Updated the question to reflect the change.

Comment: It's hard to tell what your problem is without knowing the exact method signature of `serviceUtil.getDataFromEndpoint(...)`.

Comment: Sorry about missing that detail, I have updated the question to include that.

Comment: You should rework your question by providing real code as text, not as images. This is not welcome here and also it is painful to read and analyze.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I have updated the question to use code instead of images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `getDataFromEndpoint(...)` method is generic in its return type and its `T` type argument is inferred solely from the return type of the method argument passed in by providing

```
<T> T Mockito.any(Class<T> type)
```

which, as you pass in a class literal `TypeToken.class` is only `Class<TypeToken>`, and not the desired type `Class<TypeToken<Data>>`.

Because of this, the inferred type for `serviceUtil.getDataFromEndpoint(...)` will be `List<Object>`, instead of the desired `List<Data>`. Hence, your next step will fail, because the inferred type returned by

```
when(...)
```

will be

```
OngoingStubbing<List<Object>>
```

instead of the desired

```
OngoingStubbing<List<Data>>
```

and that only accepts `List<Object>`, and not `List<Data>`, as `List<Data>` is not a subtype of `List<Object>`.

The solution is to provide a type witness to the generic `serviceUtil.getDataFromEndpoint(...)` in the form of

```
serviceUtil.<Data> getDataFromEndpoint(...)
```

and your code should compile with all major compilers, be it JDK, Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA or Netbeans.
[Generalized target-type inference](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/101) usually works well, but in this case you were providing the wrong arguments for it to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this solved the issue. Good to know we can call generics methods in this way.